# When water is evaporated and the particles with a little more energy breaks away, Why do the molecules left have less motion?

Tags: energy, water, evaporation

From Feynman's Six easy pieces:

> Then a molecule leaves it is due to an accidental, extra accumulation of a little bit more than ordinary energy, which it needs if it is to break away from the attractions of its neighbors. Therefore, since those that leave have more energy than the average, the ones that are left have less average motion than they had before. So the liquid gradually cools if it evaporates

Why do the molecules which are left have less motion?
I can't understand why. Is it because there are fewer molecules for them to jiggle against and get more speed?
Could someone please explain?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suppose you measure the average speed of three molecules. Then you take away the molecule that has the highest speed. What will average speed of the remaining two molecules be? Higher or lower than the previous average?

Comment: oh yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: thank you by the way

Comment: Feynman doesn't say the individual molecules that are left behind have less motion. He says "..the ones that are left have less average motion than they had before"